# first line in listview should be different

Tags: listview

i would like to add a line ("click here to add..") like in the outlook -> contacts.
there below the column title the first line is different from the other line and has another functionality.
its not part of the ItemContent

in my xaml i have listview with editable textbox.

```
 <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <!--  <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ColumnTitle}" />-->
                                <GridViewColumn Width="290" Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ColumnTitle}" >
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                           <local:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="23" />

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                                <GridViewColumn Width="10"  >
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <local:EditableTextBlock Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Height="23" />

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
```

Comment: You need to add a Header View to your listview and thats it. Header-view always stays on top, no matter how much the list is scrolled.

Comment: but i need that the first line will look different from the header and from all the other lines as well.

Comment: do u have any example? all the example i found is changes on the header itself